# mac osx terminal command for adding only new files and subfolders?

Tags: macos

I have 6 folders which includes files and subfolders. I need to copy those 6 folders to a target with the same 6 foldernames which also includes files and subfolders. However only new files and subfolders should be added to the target, so the 6 target folders should not be fully replaced.

Just looking for proper the (mac osx) terminal command to do that?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123608

Comment: thnx (!) that worked. Now if I want ALSO to add NEWER files with a more recent date (so not just new files) how to do that?